# Copy speed to usb flash drive very slow when partitioned as NTFS

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, fat32

So I have a 16GB Corsair Flash Voyager USB flash drive. I am on a fairly new install of Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1.

I use the flash drive for one thing, watching things on my TV.  I will copy both TV Episodes and Movies onto it.

When I use it for TV Episodes, having it formatted as a FAT32 partition is fine, as almost all shows are under 4gb's.  When I copy over to it, it all works without issue, I can multi-task, doing 4 things at once, no problem.
When I use it for watching Movies, I need to have it formatted as an NTFS partition, as almost all 1080p movies are over 4gb's.  This is where the problems arise.
When I first start the transfer, I get amazing speeds, way more than with it being a FAT32, but after a short while, my computer starts getting slow, things like my internet browser start to hang, navigating my documents, or any other directory for that matter, will also take forever to load.  Basically my computer becomes unusable while the files are transferring.
It also seems to take a long time to actually finish copying.  I haven't actually compared times, since the movies are longer, they should take longer, but it seems like it takes a lot longer (30-40 minutes for a 9GB movie, vs 5-10 for 3 or 4 x 1 to 1.5GB tv shows...)

TL:DR Any idea why I would be seeing a complete system slowdown when copying over to an NTFS partitioned flash drive, when there is no issue at all with the FAT32 partitioned drive?

Comment: I am seeing speeds of less than 1K per second. I suspect it is one of the many spyware elements of windows - indexing, telemetry, sample submission, you know - all the shit that you can't turn off.

Answer (score 1):

In Device Manager, right-click the USB drive in the Disk drives category, then select Properties, switch to Policies tab, and choose "Optimize for performance". Click OK to keep it.

Note: If you use this method, make sure you use the "Safely remove hardware" icon that appears in the notification area when you plug in the device (the notification area is the little area near the clock on the taskbar).